# Listing out the names of named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works fine but not as expected. I turned a range into a table and renamed it but it doesn't enter the loop. I then added another named range without turning it into a table and it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetNamesFromNamedRanges()

Dim MyName As Name

For Each MyName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print MyName.Name, MyName.RefersTo
Next MyName

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

I realize what I had done wrong. The reason why I didn't get the expected output was because I changed the name of the table in the name manager but it still remained a table, just with a new name. Thus, `For Each MyName In ActiveWorkbook.Names` did not print it. When I changed it to a new name, apart from name manager, it worked as expected.

Comment: I opened a new sheet, added a named ranged via the `Name Manager` and that code works fine. This will also pick up ranges created in the `worksheet` by highlighting a range and then naming it in the cell reference pane. It will **not** pick up ranges created in VBA i.e. `Set rngTest = Range("A1:A10")`

Comment: *not working* <-- please elaborate. You've got enough rep around here that you should now better than to ask a bad question like this. It can be improved, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

As Skip points out, the code does work:

[image]

Make sure the *Immediate Window* is visible.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I didn't realize what I had done wrong. See my update. Thanks for the reply.